# Django Blog (Post) not define

Tags: python, django-views, django-urls

I am using Django Version 1.11.3 with python language version = 3.6.3.
I am trying to add the path to the [Post App] url in the [PitonBlog] project  urls.py.I am getting an error in the virtual environment command line.
I am not sure why the system cannot find it, any ideas?

PitonBlog is my project urls.py
[image: PitonBlog urls.py code]

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include("Post.urls"))
]
```

Post- urls.py
[image: Post-urls.py code]

```
url(r'^$', Post.views.post_home)
```

command line error

```
 urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\wgori\Anaconda3\envs\Django_blogEnv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\wgori\Desktop\myDjangoProjects\PitonBlog\Post\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    url(r'^$', Post.views.post_home)
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

Comment: Try `url(r'^$', include('Post.views.post_home'))` or `import Post` in the beginning of the second file.

Comment: Django is no different from any other Python code. If you want to use something you've defined elsewhere, you need to import it.

Comment: Thank you. I will make changes to my code.

Comment: It worked. The change to the code : urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', views.post_home, name='post_home')

]